# Is it safe to send email through a python script

Tags: python, email, sh

I have a .py and a .sh file.
The .sh contains the function that send the email.
And the .py just executes it.

Now my question is, is it safe to send emails this way.
Is it the same security as sending through gmail.com?
Thx

Comment: We can't answer this - security depends on how the code is written, not whether it's .sh or .py.

Comment: This might be better addressed on http://security.stackexchange.com/. Please note however as it stands this question is not on topic for any Stack Exchange site. you will need to include your implementaiton details as well.

Comment: the .sh file is a simple sstmp code (echo "hello" | mail-s "one" emajl@emajl.com) and thr python is (import os os.system("sh hello.sh")

Comment: This question belongs on the [security](https://security.stackexchange.com) board, in my opinion.

Comment: Anyway, @GProduct you should merge scripts into one. Check [smtplib docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html) . No need for python system calls. Both clients create socket to smtp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail) (full disclosure: I'm the developer) to send from the command-line directly, or from within python.

```
pip install yagmail  # for python 2
pip3 install yagmail # for python 3

# Command line:
yagmail -u me@gmail.com -p password -t target@email.com  -c "Hello there!"
```

Or you can send in python (with some magic):

```
import yagmail
yag = yagmail.SMTP()
yag.send(contents = ["See this attachment", "/local/path/to/song.mp3"])
```

There are a bunch of tricks so you'll never have to type the password (or even username) again in a script or on the command line by using the keyring.

Have a look at the documentation of [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail), I feel like it could really save a lot of frustration.